# can't applying skins to DotNetNuke 6

Tags: dotnetnuke, skins

thanks for your attention frist.

i have dotnetnuke 6.x installed on my pc .

i install new skins  using Admin >> extentions >> manage >> install extention wizard , 
and install skins and containers seperatly According the instruction on Dotnetnuke website.

but when i install new skin, skins only load on skins page , and i cant see any part of new sking on other pages of my website . i checked all check boxes on skin editor page such as Host , site , Web site and admin .

it seems somethings not works properly on my system but i cant find the reason, how can i find it ?

Comment: Have you checked that the page doesn't maybe have a skin set to it. Go the the page where your new skin is not showing and then go the Page Settings. There you will be able to see if the page is using a specific skin.

Comment: you are right , the skin doesnt applied to whole web site.and i can apply it to evrey page by going to page setting as you said. but how i can apply the skin to whole web site and all pages en masse and totally ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin --> Site Settings** and under the appearance section choose the skin you want to use by selecting it next to the **Site Skin** option.

Once you have done that got to each page and go to **Page settings** and under **Advanced settings --> Appearance section** select the **Page Skin** combobox and select **None Specified**.

Hope this helps.